# How to capture the snapshot of all vehicles in a hour period

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I  have a table like below:

```
id    day  area   hour  occupied  free
___   ___  ____  _____   ______   ____
 1     1    2      1        10     30
 1     1    2      1        10      0
 1     1    3      1        6       3
 1     1    5      2        10      0
 2     1    3      1        10     10
 2     1    5      1        10     20
 2     1    8      1        6       3
 2     1    9      2        10      9
```

This shows that vehicle id 1 has spent in day 1, hour 1 (1st day of month 00:00:00 to 01:00:00 )m the areas it has spent in occupied and free. Likewise, I have the total records of 10 vehicles.

From this I would like to calculate the hourly wise occupied free and occupied vehicles.

For example 
I want something like below:

```
day      hour      free_vehicles  occupied_vehicles
____    _____     ___________    ______________
 1         1           8               2
 1         2           7               3
 1         3           6               4
```

Is possible to derive something like this? Because for a whole time interval it cannot be fully occupied or fully free. So how can I achieve this? Actually it is a snapshot of all vehicles during a time period.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. "Id" is an ID for one vehicle? It appears in the first table that Id:1 spent 26 (minutes?) occupied and 33 (minutes?) free in the 1st hour? If that's the case, I don't see how the 2nd table splits those times up into 3 different "hour: 1" rows. But in the 2nd table, cols 3 & 4 refer to "vehicleS", so then there should be more vehicles appearing in the first table for the 1st hour of the first day, but all that I see are apparently one vehicle in the first table, if the Id is any indication.

Comment: Yes "Id" is an ID for one vehicle.Sorry the second table had a typo error.Yes the col 3 and 4 are vehicles which means for day 1 hour 1 there are 8 vehicles free and 2 occupied for whole time since there are only 10 vehicles at total

Comment: Can you show the output that corresponds to the input data you show? In your sample data you have 6 rows that are both day 1 and hour 1. Their occupied values are 10, 10, 6, 10, 10, 6 and the free values are 30, 0, 3, 10, 20, 3. How do those values turn into 8 and 2 (from your sample output)?